# 2012 MSSQL Job Failing to insert into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

We are running 2012 MSSQL and have a number a jobs running to send messages.... They insert into another table into a mysql database. Problem is once in a while the job will fail for absolutely no reason. It runs find then fails.

Here is the error in the Job Log File Viewer:

> Description: The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MySQL"
> reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the
> error.  End Error  Error: 2023-11-14 18:53:52.06     Code: 0xC002F210
> Source: Transfer to machine2 Execute SQL Task     Description:
> Executing the query "INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(table_to_insert, 'SELECT
> sql_id..." failed with the following error: "The OLE DB provider
> "MSDASQL" for linked server "machine2" could not INSERT INTO table
> "[MSDASQL]". Unknown provider error.". Possible failure reasons:
> Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
> parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
> End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
> Started:  6:53:50 PM  Finished: 6:53:52 PM  Elapsed:  1.794 seconds.
> The package execution failed.  The step failed.

What makes it worse is that the same process works sometimes, but then other times it does not. It is performing an insert query on a mysql db and for example inserts 1-2 out of 15-20 then stops and throws an error.

Wouldn't it not work at all instead of the 1-2 inserts then fail?

We're using SSIS VB files to perform the transfer (insert) into the MySQL table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on why the inserts are actually failing. Unless you have an intermittent network connection then it's probably not actually a connection error. e.g.: it could be intermittent because only some rows are failing against check or foreign key constraints.

Comment: Is it the same few inserts that always fail? Or is it kind of randomly spread out over the different tasks?

Comment: My guess would be problems with Nulls not being accepted in the MySQL columns. BTW Text import and export systems in SQL Server (including SSIS) have a strange default behaviour by design where they convert Null to NullString and NullString to Null.

Comment: It is absolutely random.... no pattern to it at all. I suspect it is a resource issue at first.... but it's not.